# Normalization - Automatic global Android media sound (music videos on YouTube) adjustment

Tags: audio, automation, youtube, music, volume-control

I'm using this app: [PVSTAR+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.asbit.pvstar). I have my list which plays in an endless loop, but the problem is that some YouTube videos are louder and some are quieter. I want the audio to be constantly at a certain "loudness level". What I need is a way to "normalizes" the Android volume on the fly.

I found an app called [Waver - Volume Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rebuildlabs.waver), but it says it is not compatible with my Android 4.1 device; the app requires 2.3. Anyway, I downloaded the APK of waver and installed it but it seems not to be working.

Is there a way to adjust the media audio on a certain level automatically, so it automatically detects that the current audio is too low and increases it?