# Is there an app or setting for *volume* equalization?

Tags: samsung, audio, equalizer

Whenever I go to sleep, I always have a playlist of YouTube videos playing in the background (on my phone, not a computer or TV). There are several videos or series that I would love to add to my "background noise" playlist; unfortunately, the volume itself on the audio wavers far too much, to the point that the volume I set on my phone is either too high that it risks waking me up shortly after falling asleep, or too low that I cannot hear half of the video.

I have tried searching through various apps on the Google Play Store, but it seems most of them try to equalize volume based on frequency (such as treble and bass), and not intensity (in decibels). I am looking for an app (or if it exists, a setting in my phone) where I can set a limit of __ to __ decibels, and all audio coming out of my phone will be within that range (similar to noise gating but with output instead of input).

If anyone has a solution or app out there that would fit this description, please do let me know. Thank you in advance!

I have tried browsing around in the audio settings on my Galaxy S22+ but have not seen anything that would help. I have also downloaded about 5 or 6 different equalizer apps, but again, they all were based on frequency and not intensity/volume itself.

Comment: What you are searching for is called "audio normalization"

Comment: Possible duplicates, but not yet properly answered: [How to automatically normalize loudness system-wide?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/211782/44325), [Normalization - Automatic global Android media sound (music videos on YouTube) adjustment](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/87958/44325)